# How could a puzzle-based locking mechanism work?

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, locks

I've sometimes seen boxes that feature a sliding puzzle or other mechanical puzzle on the lid which, when solved, opens the box.

Advantages and applications mostly seem novelty and leisure, but I am wondering how one could mechanically construct such a puzzle?

Comment: Can someone please provide help in making this more specific? This question concerns parts of a puzzle that need to be manually moved in place (Ivo Beckers gave a good example with a 24-sliding puzzle). Only when completely solved should be box or other compartment be able to open.

Comment: There are many many examples which is why this is too broad...here are several that can be 3d printed easily http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:830293   http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:32053   http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:21658   http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:201097

Answer (score 3):

Well, googling "slide puzzle lock" give me the following first hit, so it really isn't hard to find:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Mysterious-Sliding-Tile-Secret-Compartment-Table/

This seems to be a step by step guide to make a table with a compartment locked by sliding tile puzzle. I haven't really examined it thoroughly but it seems to work by having mag locks at different locations and the tiles having magnets at different locations.

Searching the web probably gives you other examples as well.

Comment: While good (and I've been over that design)  it requires only 2 out of 24 tiles to actually be in place. Is that a common flaw of these puzzles?

Comment: Wow so its as effective as a 'safe' that was in a mickey mouse magazine when i was a kid. They supplied a 4 Digit Code in the Magazine to open the safe, but it did not take me long to figure out that there were only two discs in the safe wich made it comepletly unnecessary to put in the first two numbers.. But i guess you could hope people will never notice and blissfully enter a four digit code..